# Why does git only have 1 workspace?

Tags: git, svn, workspace

Compared to subversion which you can start many workspaces. Why can't a git repository have more than 1 workspace so switching branches doesn't necessitate restitution of state before throwing away your current branch. If I'm frustrated by a svn checkout, I just blow it away and start a new one. In git, I want to maintain my local repo (and haven't pushed remotely) so I can't just clone a new repo.

Comment: You can clone your local repo, of course.

Answer (score 1):

With Git, there are a couple of ways to handle this:

***git stash*** will store your working copy into a temporary area to allow you to switch branches without having committed. ***git stash apply*** will lay your changes back down. The two work in a push/pop stack-style mechanism. It is possible to keep multiple stashes and apply from an arbitrary stash, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Throwing out code is a little easier: ***git reset --hard HEAD*** will clear your working state and revert it to the last HEAD in the current branch you're working on. This would be equivalent to deleting your working copy and checking it out again.